# How to check document is encrypted or not in iOS application

Tags: ios, passwords, document, password-encryption

I use webView to preview documents like PDF,Word,PPT. My requirement is to check whether the document is password protected  before loading into the webview.

I use below function for PDF

bool CGPDFDocumentIsEncrypted ( CGPDFDocumentRef document );

I just wanted to know how to find out document is password protected  for word, ppt,other documents.

Please provide the possible ways to accomplish the above requirement.

Comment: If the document is encrypted the data will look like random bytes with **no pattern**.

Comment: Thanks Zaph, can you please share some more basic info about  "If the document is encrypted the data will look like random bytes with no pattern" Is there any ways like " document.isEncrypted" functionalities available to check the document is password protected??...

Answer (score 0):

The only way to tell is something is encrypted is to be able to tell if it is not encrypted and the only way to tell that is to look at the data and see if it makes sense. Look at each type of file and check for something that must be there, usually there is a pre-amble that can be checked.

An example: a .jpg file will always start with the 4 byte Application marker:  0xff 0xd8 0xff 0xe0.

For all the file types you want to determine encryption of lookup the file formats and write code to verify them.

Encryption changes the data bytes in such a way that they can not be discerned from random bits and bytes, if it is possible to tell anything from the encrypted bytes the encryption method has failed. That is the whole point of encryption.